# Probability under Beta distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, beta-distribution

Let $f_a$ be the density function of a random variable $X_a$ which has a Beta distribution with parameters $na$ and $ma;$
that is,

$$f_a(x) = \frac{1}{B(na,ma)}\, x^{na-1} (1-x)^{ma-1},\quad  0 \lt x \lt 1. $$

How can I prove the conjecture that when $n\gt m$ and $a\gt 0,$ $\Pr[X_a\gt1/2] = \int_{1/2}^1 f_a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is increasing in $a$?

Comment: Note that when n=m, the above probability is 1/2 for every a.